# How to create a matrix from two given vectors in R in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, matrix

Suppose, $c(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $c(2, 4, 5, 6)$ are two vectors. Then in R or RStudio,

> How to create a $4\times 2$ matrix from these two vectors?

Also,

> how to add another vector $c(8, 9, 10, 11)$ as a column to the previous matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

y <- c(2, 4, 5, 6)

z <- matrix(c(x, y), nrow = length(x))

zz <- cbind(z, c(8, 9, 10, 11))
```

Comment: The first solution works but is not as instructive as a simple `cbind(x, y)`.

Comment: @Nick F, it says that "function lenght is not found". How to fix this issue?

Comment: @MichaelM  It says that "function lenght is not found". How to fix this issue?

Comment: By switching the t and the h ;-)

Comment: @MichaelM fair point on cbind for all parts being cleaner.

Comment: @MichaelM I am still finding difficulty. I am very new to R and RStuudio. I have installed R and RStudio software and installed commads, plyr, MAAS, ggplot2 and dplyr. Am i missing any commands to create a matrix from given vectors?

Comment: @gete The “cbind” command is part of R when it installs, so you have it. I suppose you could check with a “?cbind” command to make sure it gives you the documentation instead of saying it’s never heard of that function, but you should have “cbind”. One you determine that you have the “cbind” function, are “x <- cbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(2,4,5,6))” and “y <- cbind(x, c(8,9,10,11))” not giving you the results you want? If they are not, what do you not like about those results?

Comment: @Dave It seems fine now. I have used- print(x), print(y) print(z) and print(zz)

Comment: @gete You should be able to display the object by just entering, for instance, “zz” and hitting enter.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, its working ...